# ナブラの内積を計算したいです

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

∇（ナブラ）を使って内積 ∇・b の計算をしたいのですが、ここからどうすればうまくいくのでしょうか。３を出力したいです。

```
import numpy as np
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')

del_x = np.gradient(,dx)
del_y = np.gradient(,dy)
del_z = np.gradient(,dz)
nabra = np.array([del_x,del_y,del_z])
b = np.array([x,y,z])
np.inner(nabla,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

まず、SymPy と NumPy の違いをご理解ください。SymPy はシンボリック計算のためのライブラリで、NumPy は数値計算のためのライブラリです。

その上で、SymPy にはベクトル場を表すための関数が用意されています。このドキュメントをご覧ください：[Scalar and Vector Field Functionality](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/fields.html)

サンプルプログラムです：

```
>>> from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, Del, divergence
>>> # 座標系を決めます
... C = CoordSys3D('C')
>>> # ナブラは Del() として定義されています
... nabla = Del()
>>> # C.i, C.j, C.k が標準的な基底、C.x, C.y, C.z がベクトル場の仮引数です
... b = C.x * C.i + C.y * C.j + C.z * C.k
>>> # 内積は dot です
... nabla.dot(b)
Derivative(C.x, C.x) + Derivative(C.y, C.y) + Derivative(C.z, C.z)
>>> # 微分計算をしてもらうためには doit() を使います
... nabla.dot(b).doit()
3
>>> # ナブラとの内積は divergence としても定義されています
... divergence(b).doit()
3
```